# How to fix OutOfMemoryException for PerformanceCounterCategory.GetInstanceName

Tags: c#, .net, performancecounter

If I execute this code

```
PerformanceCounterCategory cat = new PerformanceCounterCategory("Process");
var instances = cat.GetInstanceNames(); // OutOfMemoryException
```

I get an `OutOfMemoryException` The full stack trace is

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
System.OutOfMemoryException: An Exception of Type "System.OutOfMemoryException" occured.
   at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.InternalGetValue(String name, Object defaultValue, Boolean doNotExpand, Boolean checkSecurity)
   at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.GetValue(String name)
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceMonitor.GetData(String item)
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.GetPerformanceData(String item)
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.get_CategoryTable()
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.GetCategorySample(String machine, String category)
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory.GetCounterInstances(String categoryName, String machineName)
   at WindowsFormsApplication5.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

This only happens in an x64 exe if  I run the same code under x86 it works. Any ideas how to solve this?

OS is Windows 8.1 x64, with 8GB RAM (this is not a physical memory issue).

Comment: And how much free memory do you have just prior to the problem call?

Comment: 'OS is Windows 8.1 x64, with 8GB RAM (this is not a physical memory issue).' => yes, but the 'real' problem may be elsewhere in the code, i.e. you get the out of memory calling cat.GetInstanceNames(); but want to confirm you have headroom prior to that call and the issue is not abnormal memory use elsewhere.  So can you explicity confirm free memory prior to that call.

Comment: Also what are the contents of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Perflib\009 registry key and C:\Windows\System32\perfc009.dat file (its a text file, if its large just post its sze)

Comment: @tolanj That was the right hint, I rebuild performance counters from the disk.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually solved this with a knowlegebase article [How to manually rebuild Performance Counter Library values](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/300956)

1. Backup `Perfc009.dat` and `Perfh009.dat` in `%Systemroot%\System32`
2. Copy the files from the installation media to %Systemroot%\System32. While this kb article is for server 2008 and I am on windows 8.1 I extracted the files from the installation dvd's file `sources\install.wim` (folder `2\Windows\System32\` for Windows 8 Pro) with 7-zip.
3. In the registry, change the Last Counter value to 1846 (decimal), and change the Last Help value to 1847 (decimal).
4. Remove the following values from the Performance subkey (if they exist): `First Counter, First Help, Last Counter, Last Help`
5. Use `lodctr /R` (I did this from an admin cmd prompt once in System32 and Syswow64 folder just to be sure) to reenable third party counters
6. The article also suggests, if any .NET applications fail to start, you have to reinstall .NET assemblies that create performance counters, e.g. `InstallUtil /i Microsoft.Mom.ConfigService.dll` but that was not necessary in my case.

Comment: Good for you. Often you can get away with simply running the `lodctr /R` command (without doing any of the other steps).

Comment: Hmm, I'm not buying.  Did you forget to list step 6a. Reboot machine?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError - Not in my case, I also tried `lodctr /q` and `loadctr /d:<servicename>` for some third party performance counters.
@HansPassant - Noop, this worked for me without reboot, even without restarting any performance counter related service.